# Todonote beside figures/floats

Tags: floats, todonotes

I am facing a very basic problem when working with the [`todonotes`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/todonotes) package. How can I place a todonote right beside a figure?

I would really appreciate a simple solution such as a modified `todo` command, since these comments are just temporary todo notes...

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{todonotes}

\usepackage{blindtext} % for dummy text
\usepackage{tikz}      % for dummy pic

\begin{document}    
  \blindtext % dummy paragraph

  \begin{figure} % dummy figure
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}\draw(0,0) rectangle (5,3);\end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{dummy caption}
  \end{figure}%
  \todo[noline]{I need this comment to be situated beside the figure...}  

  \blindtext % dummy paragraph  
\end{document}
```

[image: problem description]

Comment: You can put a note next to a figure with \marginnote, but not with \todo (or \marginpar).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{todonotes}
\usepackage{marginnote}

\usepackage{blindtext} % for dummy text
\usepackage{tikz}      % for dummy pic

\begin{document}    
  \blindtext % dummy paragraph

  \begin{figure} % dummy figure
    \marginnote{I need this comment to be situated beside the figure...}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}\draw(0,0) rectangle (5,3);\end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{dummy caption}

  \end{figure}%
  \todo{this note will show up on the todo list}


  \blindtext % dummy paragraph  
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you. Inspired by your answer I have found a proper solution for me. I have introduced a new command for the figure case `\newcommand{\ftodo}[1]{\marginnote{\begin{minipage}{2.4cm}\todo[inline]{#1}\end{minipage}}}`. This allows for the same outcome and an update of the todo-list. In two-sided document it might be a good decision to even replace all todo-notes with this comment `\let\temptodo\todo \renewcommand{\todo}[1]{\marginnote{\begin{minipage}{2.4cm}\temptodo[inline]{#1}\end{minipage}}}`

Comment: BTW, \marginnote already has options to allow larger "notes", so the minipage may not be needed.

Comment: @JohnKormylo Thx, works for me without `minipage`.