# Using hyperref's autoref function with todonotes messes up reference names

Tags: hyperref, inline, todonotes

I used \autoref throughout my thesis and when doing corrections and needing to keep track of them using the todonotes package, I noticed that the \autoref function generates wrong labels.

To show what I mean, here's MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{todonotes}

\begin{document}
\section{ABC}
\section{DEF}
\section{EFG}
\section{HIJ}

\begin{figure}
\centering
XXX
\caption{Three Xs}
\label{fig:XXX}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\centering
YYY
\caption{Three Y's \todo[inline]{remove the apostrophe}}
\label{fig:YYY}
\end{figure}

Should be Figure 1: \autoref{fig:XXX}


Should be Figure 2: \autoref{fig:YYY}

\end{document}
```

This is what it generates:
[image: MWE problem with autoref]

I read around and it seems that it may be doing that because as soon as you insert any todonotes in the caption, it thinks that it's the main body and then the following label then refers to the section (but somehow keeps the figure's counter). This is clearly wrong.

Putting label before \caption doesn't work.
Putting all todonotes after \caption is not suitable as the corrections are WITHIN caption.

Could anybody suggest a solution, please?

Many thanks,
Nickolai.

Comment: By the way, if somebody wants their todonotes in the margins, I stumbled across this while searching: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/217633/todonote-beside-figures-floats

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a suggestion that's not a direct solution to the problem with `\autoref` but, instead, a robust *alternative* to using `\autoref`.

Load the [cleveref](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/cleveref/) package with the options `noabbrev`, `nameinlink`, and `capitalize` (`capitalise` works too...), and issue the instruction

```
\cref{fig:YYY}
```

instead of `\autoref{fig:YYY}`.

(The options `noabbrev`, `nameinlink`, and `capitalize` serve to make the output of `\cref` look like that of `\autoref`.)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{todonotes}
\usepackage[noabbrev,nameinlink,capitalize]{cleveref}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
XXX
\caption{Three Xs}
\label{fig:XXX}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\centering
YYY
\caption{Three Y's \todo[inline]{remove the apostrophe}}
\label{fig:YYY}
\end{figure}
Should be Figure 1: \autoref{fig:XXX}, \cref{fig:XXX}

Should be Figure 2: \autoref{fig:YYY}, \cref{fig:YYY}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Awesome!!! I should have used the cleverref package to start with (there were few places with multiple references where I had to put the names in manually and when my supervisor said that section should be in capital Section - I had renew the label as per manual and to be careful throughout the whole thesis). What I did now is a cheat:
    \usepackage[noabbrev, capitalise, nameinlink]{cleveref}
    \renewcommand{\autoref}{\cref}
Seems to be working ;-)

Comment: @Nickolai - On redefining `\autoref` to make it work like `\cref`: I would suggest either `\let\autoref\cref` or `\renewcommand{\autoref}[1]{\cref{#1}}`. Alernatively, in your text editor, do a global search-and-replace of "autoref" for "cref", making a redefinition of `\autoref` unnecessary.